# Transforming a five variable Lagrangian function to three variable function results different minima values

Tags: multivariable-calculus, lagrange-multiplier, maxima-minima

I have used one of the two available constraints to reduce the number of variables in my Lagrangian equation. As a result, I got different minima value. What is wrong with this approach?

[image]

Comment: Welcome to MSE. It is in your best interest that you type your questions (using [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference)) instead of posting links to pictures.

Comment: Nothing wrong with the approach. Your solution in the first method is wrong. [Check it out again](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=minimize+x%5E2%2By%5E2%2Bz%5E2+subject+to+3x%2B4y%2B5z%3D7+and+x%3Dz%2B9).

Comment: thanks a lot @A.Γ.